# Paper-scroll-header-panel with toolbars that remain once they reach the top

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am trying to use Polymer's `paper-scroll-header-panel` as the base for my app and need to have a submenu (`paper-toolbar`) that starts a ways down the page "stick" underneath the main header once it gets there. I have it laid out like this currently but as expected the second toolbar scrolls up under the header once it gets there:

```
<paper-scroll-header-panel condenses keep-condensed-header>
    <paper-toolbar class="tall layout horizontal" id="title-toolbar">
      <div class="bottom bottom-container horizontal layout">
        <div class="bottom-title paper-font-subhead">Title</div>
      </div>

    </paper-toolbar>
    <div id="content" class="content-dark">
      <div class="horizontal center-justified layout">
        <!-- some body content here -->
      </div>

      <paper-toolbar justify="center"> <!-- this is the toolbar that needs to stick once it scroll up under the header-->
          <paper-tabs selected="{{selected}}" class="fit" scrollable>
              <paper-tab>1</paper-tab>
              <paper-tab>2</paper-tab>
              <paper-tab>3</paper-tab>
              <paper-tab>4</paper-tab>
          </paper-tabs>
      </paper-toolbar>
        <iron-pages selected="{{selected}}">
            <div><!-- page content --></div>
            <div><!-- page content --></div>
            <div><!-- page content --></div>
            <div><!-- page content --></div>
        </iron-pages>
    </div>
  </paper-scroll-header-panel>
```

Extra question (optional, but desired!) - How can I access the `paper-scroll-header-panel` scroll functionality via javascript? I want to mimic [this effect](https://css-tricks.com/scroll-fix-content/) but using `$('#id').scroll(function(e){//stuff}));` doesn't seem to work and it appears to be because that is targeting the main window scroll and this polymer element creates its own scroll area within the window. Looking at [the element's code on github](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-scroll-header-panel/blob/master/paper-scroll-header-panel.html) I can see it has a `scroller()` function and an `sTop` variable that is equal to `this.scroller.scrollTop` which I think I will need but I am not really sure how to access these in Polymer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve both these issues in a similar way:

```
addEventListener('content-scroll', function() {
var scroller = document.querySelector('paper-scroll-header-panel').scroller.scrollTop;
if (scroller >= 150) //magic numbers ugh
{ //add classes for fixed } else { //remove classes for fixed }
});
```

I am not sure if this is the best method but it seems to work.